# Plugin support for gcc in RHEL/CentOS?

Tags: centos, rhel, gcc, plugin

Is there anyway to enable or install plugin support for gcc in RHEL/CentOS?

Comment: The `-fplugin` option doesn't work? What version of `RHEL`?

Comment: what you want to achieve ? just want to packages which help to compile packages or what ?

Comment: I would like to do it at least on RHEL 6 and hopefully RHEL 5. Specifically, I'm trying to build and use [odb](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/odb/) and it requires plugin support for gcc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugin support for GCC was added in [4.5](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.5/changes.html) and so it is not available in RHEL 5 and 6 without building a newer version of GCC from source or without using the [devtoolset](http://www.redhat.com/summit/2012/pdf/2012-DevDay-How-To-Toolset-Newsome.pdf).

Also, a branch was made to [backport plugin support to gcc 4.4](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2009-11/msg00782.html), but I'm not sure what the status of that build is and it doesn't appear to be available as an RPM for CentOS/RHEL.

Answer (score -1):

```
15:13 [root:~]# yum search gcc
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: 
 * extras: 
 * rpmforge: 
 * updates: 
===================================================== N/S Matched: gcc ======================================================
compat-libgcc-296.i686 : Compatibility 2.96-RH libgcc library
gcc-c++.i686 : C++ support for GCC
gcc-gnat.i686 : Ada 95 support for GCC
gcc-java.i686 : Java support for GCC
gcc-objc.i686 : Objective-C support for GCC
gcc-objc++.i686 : Objective-C++ support for GCC
libgcc.i686 : GCC version 4.4 shared support library
compat-gcc-34.i686 : Compatibility GNU Compiler Collection
compat-gcc-34-c++.i686 : C++ support for compatibility compiler
compat-gcc-34-g77.i686 : Fortran 77 support for compatibility compiler
gcc.i686 : Various compilers (C, C++, Objective-C, Java, ...)
gcc-gfortran.i686 : Fortran support
libgcj.i686 : Java runtime library for gcc
libgcj-devel.i686 : Libraries for Java development using GCC
libgcj-src.i686 : Java library sources from GCC4 preview
libgomp.i686 : GCC OpenMP v3.0 shared support library
libmudflap.i686 : GCC mudflap shared support library
libmudflap-devel.i686 : GCC mudflap support
```

Comment: I had looked at that list before posting this and, at least from the descriptions, none of those seemed to provide support for plugin usage with gcc.